# How to notify threads when modal dialog becomes visible?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, modal-dialog

I am setting a modal dialog as visible in a SwingWorker thread using SwingUtilities.invokeLater. I want the SwingWorker thread to wait until the dialog becomes visible. What is the best way to do this? I have put the following code in my doInBackground() method in the SwingWorker object.

```
synchronized (myDialog) {
    while (!myDialog.isVisible()) {
            myDialog.wait();
    }
}
```

And in the overridden setVisible() method in the MyDialog class:

```
public void setVisible(boolean enabled) {
    synchronized (this) {
        notifyAll();
    }

    super.setVisible(enabled);
}
```

However, this does not seem to work as there is a timing issue - notifyAll() must be called before super.setVisible() and as a result the SwingWorker thread can be left in a waiting state.

I'm trying to figure out a nice way to do this but I'm getting pretty frustrated!

Comment: hmm .. don't quite understand why you want a worker _wait_ until the dialog is visible. My first (maybe naive) approach would be to _execute_ it only after the dialog is visible (f.i. in a WindowListener)

Comment: @kleopatra - I guess I could put the notifyAll() in the WindowListener instead of in the setVisible() method.

Comment: I guess you need to better explain _what_ exactly you are trying to achieve (vs. how an assumed solution doesn't do what you expect). Time for an SSCCE

Comment: You can use SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait

Answer (score 1):

- use `JOptionPane` instead of plain `JDialog`
- `JOptionPane` block code execution untill some action realized
- you can to add `JComponents` to `JOptionPane` same as for `JDialog`

Comment: How might I use a JOptionPane in the scenario I have described? Surely I would have the same issue?

Comment: nobody know whats happened, how to say whatever cleaver without posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), my reply is about simplest of ways

Answer (score 1):

Do not manipulate the dialog from the worker's `doInBackground()` method. Instead `publish()` an appropriate result and make the dialog visible from `process()`. You can also register a `PropertyChangeListener` that will be fired in response to `setProgress()` calls from `doInBackground()`. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513) illustrates both mechanisms.

As an aside, I would reiterate @kleopatra's and @mKorbel's suggestion to better explain *what* exactly you are trying to achieve.